# Excel 2010: Not repainted bug

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010 (x86/32-bit) on Windows 7 64-bit. I have been suffering from this repainting bug. When I press page down/up, some portion of the sheet doesn't properly updated or repainted.

In the attached image, there are bunch of empty rows. They should be repainted. Only after dragging these areas, they are repainted.

I have installed SP1 and tried to find any hot fixes, but no good result yet. Is there anyone who has this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing graphical weirdness in any other programs?  Have you tried updating your video drivers?

Comment: This happens on a 64bit machine with me as well, both in the corporate workplace, and at home. It seems to be particular to 64 bit systems I guess.

Comment: It was a problem due to video driver.

Comment: @Nullptr Could you add the video driver solution as an answer and mark the question as answered?